# out of memory error imageview

Tags: android, image, imageview

I would like to set programmatically an image on my ImageView,
but when I try to put a jpg file I get an error.
This is my Code:

```
VideoView videoview;
    ImageView immagine;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        immagine = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        immagine.setImageResource(R.drawable.aresbkg);
```

and this is the logicat:

```
Process: com.lorenzofusinato.b_happy.cambiobutton, PID: 5481
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 715478412 byte allocation with 2982288 free bytes and 379MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:767)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:358)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:93)
        at com.lorenzofusinato.b_happy.cambiobutton.activity_main.onCreate(activity_main.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

How can I solve this problem? It isn't my first time whit the ImageView so I don't know why in this case I get this error. In my other applications everything goes ok.
Thank a lot.
Lorenzo

Comment: How large is that image? You might need to load subsampled image to preserve memory.

Comment: my size is 2,5mb

Comment: The allocation is for 715 megabytes. There's some layouter bug or something like that. I doubt the image is that big. I'm investigating a huge memory allocation with the same LoadDrawableForCookie. Changing the layout to use picasso or something instead might fix it, but this leaves core reason unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to avoid OOM.

Answer (score 1):

A good old OutOfMemory: in any case, 2.5 mb is too big just for display on Android device, I think.

Maybe could you use a library like Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) to resize your image ? (like @Devit 951 suggested it first)